# print.module error - Warning: file_put_contents

Tags: files

I am using the print.module and dompdf to convert the PDF files. I am getting the following warning on my pages. How would I go about fixing this?

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Times-Bold.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Cpdf->openFont() (line 2354 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php).
>
> Notice: Constant DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR already defined in require_once() (line 73 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php).
>
> Notice: Constant DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP already defined in require_once() (line 185 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php).
>
> Notice: Constant DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE already defined in require_once() (line 196 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the INSTALL.txt file.  You need to give the webserver write access to the dompdf/lib/fonts directory.

In my case, I chowned it to apache:apache.  Make it mirror how you have your sites/default/files directory set up.

Comment: Thank you @MPD

These are not the correct permissions, is that right?
drwxr-xr-x - fonts directory

Comment: It totally depends on your situation.  My folder is owned by apache, so I can use 755 permissions.  Make it the same group/owner as sites/default/files and the same permissions.